# TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined (línea 67, archivo "Código")

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

Recibo el error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined (línea 67, archivo "Código")

Al procesar un *JSON*, el contenido del *JSON* es:

```
{"TimeStamp":"XXX","Operador":"XXX","FirmanteNombre":"XXX","FirmanteNIF":"XXX","FirmanteCorreo":"XXX","FirmanteMovil":"XXX","FirmaLocalizador":"XXX","FirmaHashSMS":"XXX","FirmaHashMail":"XXX","FicheroHash":"XXX","FicheroName":"XXX"}
```

Compruebo que el JSON es legible y no contiene errores en formato:

[image: Lectura JSON]

El código para leer el JSON

```
var data = JSON.parse(json)
  var TimeStamp = data.TimeStamp
  var Firmante = data.FirmanteNombre
  var NIF = data.FirmanteNIF
  var OriginalMail = data.FirmanteCorreo
  var phone = data.FirmanteMovil
  var OriginalSMSKey = data.FirmaHashSMS
  var OriginalMailKey = data.FirmaHashMail
  var FileHash = data.FicheroHash
  var FileName = data.FicheroName
```

Debería de obtener los datos correctamente pero ni siquiera hace el "parse".

El JSON se obtiene de un fichero .json

```
    var rec = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer '+token
          }, muteHttpExceptions: true})
  var json = rec.getContentText()
```

He confirmado con `Logger.log(json)` que 'json' es correcto y legible.

Comment: ¿El JSON que estas usando está almacenado en una variable que se llama efectivamente `JSON`? Si fuese así se llamaria igual que el objeto `JSON` que se utiliza para acceder al método `parse`. Entonces `JSON.parse` no existe, porque no existe `parse` en tu JSON de datos. En ese caso la solución sería cambiar el nombre de la variable que tiene el JSON a algo como `dataJSON` y hacer `JSON.parse(dataJSON)`

Comment: Hasta donde tengo entendido la función JSON de GAS es JSON.parse(AQUI EL JSON)

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir tu salida de  ```console.log(JSON.stringify(json))```?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'stringify' of undefined (línea 38, archivo "Código")

Comment: Lo más probable que que en alguna parte the tu projecto hayas usado `var JSON;` o algo similar con lo que se "sobreescribió" el objeto global `JSON` como `undefined`. En cualquier caso deberías incluir un [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable que que en alguna parte the tu proyecto hayas usado `var JSON;` o algo similar con lo que se "sobreescribió" el objeto global `JSON` como `undefined` y por ello tienes los errorers de que no se encontraron (`cannot read property...  of undefined`)`parse` ni `stringify`.

Answer (score -1):

Si de algo puedo ayudar a alguien dejare esto aqui!!!!

Debes primero que todo almacenar tu json en una variable para poder parsearlo

si no estas seguro que lo tienes es un json usa **stringify()** para convertirlo a json y luego parseas con **parse()**

ejemplo

```js
let json = JSON.stringify({"TimeStamp":"XXX","Operador":"XXX","FirmanteNombre":"XXX","FirmanteNIF":"XXX","FirmanteCorreo":"XXX","FirmanteMovil":"XXX","FirmaLocalizador":"XXX","FirmaHashSMS":"XXX","FirmaHashMail":"XXX","FicheroHash":"XXX","FicheroName":"XXX"});



let pars = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(pars.TimeStamp);
```

Es lo mismo si hicieras una llamada a una api parseas el resultado y listo!!!

Comment: El JSON se obtiene de un fichero .json

    var rec = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer '+token
          }, muteHttpExceptions: true})
  var json = rec.getContentText()
He confirmado con Logger.log(json) que 'json' es correcto y legible.